# Word Processor Apps can't be opened

Tags: libreoffice

I've got some problem with word processing application. I used LibreOffice Writer, WPS Writer, etc. it always go to recovery file. But the Spreadsheet file and the Presentation file are okay when I opened it.

[image: Picture of Recovery File]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the text of any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: @OrganicMarble : i added the picture. Please take a look